# Incovertable types; Canot cast 'android.view.View' to int'

Tags: javascript, android, firebase

The Phone and etAdress are coming up with the error below:

> Canot cast 'android.view.View' to int'

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText Name;
  private int Phone;
  private EditText etEmailUser;
  private EditText Address;
  private EditText txtPassword;
  private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;@
  Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    Phone = (int) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    etEmailUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailUser);
    etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried changing private int phone to private String phone or private EditText phone? It might contain non-numeric characters?

Comment: The phone and email address are going to contain numbers which is an 'int' 

I've tried it yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `findViewById(R.id.etPhone)` will return a `View` not an `int`. In your case I think `etPhone` is an `EditText` so you should change Phone type to `EditText`

```
private EditText Phone;
...
     Phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
```